# Search for files with Tags that include a number within a range?

Tags: search, finder, tags, range

New here .

I'm on macOS (Monterey). I've come up with [a Keyboard Maestro macro that reads the ProjectData or MetaData of a Logic Pro project](https://forum.keyboardmaestro.com/t/get-logic-pro-project-info-tempo-time-signature-plugins-used/28125) to find its tempo, then tags the project file itself accordingly, using standard Finder tags. I'd like to perform a search for all files whose tagged BPM falls within a certain range (e.g. 10BPM).

Let's say I have some files tagged like so: "BPM: 108", "BPM: 112", "BPM: 119", "BPM: 125"

Is it possible to search for: Tags containing "BPM" *and* a number +/-5 of 115?

That search would return the files tagged: "BPM: 112" and "BPM: 119".

I've come up with a macro that generates a long search string, which in this case would be:

```
Tag:"BPM: 110" OR Tag:"BPM: 111" OR Tag:"BPM: 112" OR Tag:"BPM: 113" OR Tag:"BPM: 114" OR Tag:"BPM: 115" OR Tag:"BPM: 116" OR Tag:"BPM: 117" OR Tag:"BPM: 118" OR Tag:"BPM: 119" OR Tag:"BPM: 120"
```

It works, but I was wondering if there might be a more elegant solution.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: This question is likely to be closed.  If you would like it answered, then you need to explain it a bit more.  For example, what OS, what sort of files (text, code, binary), and how are you tagging the files?

Comment: Is this ia custom tag? Why not use the `Beats-per-minute` property available to the common music formats.

Comment: @RohitGupta, I do apologise; this is my first time using this forum.

I'm on macOS (Monterey). I've come up with a Keyboard Maestro macro that reads the MetaData in a Logic Pro project to find its tempo, then tags the project file itself accordingly, using standard Finder tags. 

I'd like to perform a search for all files whose tagged BPM falls within a certain range. This range would usually be, say, 10BPM.

@KeithMiller, is it possible to add the `Beats-per-minute` property to anything other than audio files?

Here's my macro:

https://tinyurl.com/2dr3ama9

Comment: There's no need to apologise, we all start in the same place.  Please edit the post to include all the information and the link.

Comment: Thankyou @RohitGupta. I've edited the post as you suggested. 